# Export content and titles from Facebook business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, export

Does anyone know how to export the titles and content off a personal fan page on Facebook?

I have added over 120 photo albums and stories and would like to keep them organized so I don't ever put the same story.

Answer (score 1):

I was at the same crossroads you've described and decided to use [SocialSafe](http://socialsafe.net/features) which has allowed me to save and organize all of the content that I have posted to my facebook page over the years.

I'm not affiliated with them at all, it's just been an incredibly helpful tool. They have a 60-day free trial, so you can get a really good sense of the product (then I decided to spring the $7 for the year- so very reasonably priced either way).